# How to properly init a vector of std::array?

Tags: c++, std

Firstly, I have a template data structure which can access elements using numeric indices. The indices can be negative.

```
class RangeList
{
public:
    RangeList(PosType off_min, PosType off_max)
        : _off_min(off_min)
        , _off_max(off_max)
        , data(off_max - off_min + 1) {}

    T& operator[] (PosType i)
    { return data[i-_off_min]; }

    const T& operator[] (PosType i) const
    { return data[i-_off_min]; }

    size_t size()
    { return data.size(); }

protected:
    PosType _off_min;
    PosType _off_max;
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

I use C++11 std::array to represent some data profile of fixed length:

```
typedef std::array<float, std::numeric_limit<uint16_t>::max()> ProfileType;
```

The question raises when these two things combined together:

```
typedef RangeList<ProfileType> ProfileRangeList;
```

Inside `RangeList`, the `data` member will be of type `vector<array<float, 65536> >`.

I noticed, if you create a std::array on the stack, its contents will be uninitialized, and you need to explicitly set its content to zero. So what happens if the std::array is a value type of std::vector?

In my test code, it seems the contents are magically initialized to zeroes, but I don't know if it obeys language standard and is reliable and reproducible.

Comment: It is fine. An `std::vector` value-initializes its elements, which has the effect of zero-initializing the contents of the arrays. Of course, if the vector is empty that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your *If you create `array` on the stack* means something akin to:

```
std::array<T,s> arr;
```

This is also valid, though:

```
std::array<T,s> arr {};
```

Which will value-initialize every field. And that's what `vector` does (to each of its `array` elements), so you're safe.